# Foundation 5 Orbit Slider inside Reveal Modal has no Height

Tags: responsive-design, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, lightbox, orbit

Here is a [**jsfiddle demonstrating the following issue**](http://jsfiddle.net/gU2XH/).

I'm using [**Foundation 5**](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework and trying to include an [**Orbit Slider**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) inside of a [**Reveal Modal**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html), however for some reason the slider is not given an appropriate height.

```
<-- Button to Reveal Modal -->
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal class="button radius">Click For Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Popup that is revealed -->
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <ul data-orbit>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that if you resize your browser window with the modal open, it automatically corrects itself to the appropriate height. This issue existed in previous versions of Foundation, so [**hacky fixes**](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2208) popped up like this:

```
$('.reveal-modal').on('opened', function(){
    $(this).find('[data-orbit]').css('height','');  
    $(window).trigger('resize.fndtn.orbit');
});
```

However this fix no longer works in the newest version of Foundation. Is there any way to get it working?

Note that I don't want to simply assign a min-height css attribute as the content in my slider will be of variable height, not to mention responsive so a pixel value wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this question. I have a similar issue but each slide needs to be a different size. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short I believe this is the answer:

```
$(document).foundation();

$('.reveal-modal').on('opened', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

OR

```
$(document).foundation();

$(document).on('opened', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

I looked at the following references:

- [Foundation 4.1.2: Orbit slider not shown in Reveal window](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2208)

  - The one you listed as "hacky fixes" above
- [Squashed picture when using Orbit in a Reveal](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2809)
- [Orbit height not set on accordion](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/3829).

It looks like the old hack for 4.1.2 just called the `compute_dimension` method to resize the modal once it was opened. I looked in the foundation.orbit.js file and found `$(window).on('resize', self.compute_dimensions);`, around line 280.

Instead of `$(window).trigger('resize.fndtn.orbit');` I used `$(window).trigger('resize');` and removed the line `$(this).find('[data-orbit]').css('height','');`.

I forked your [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gU2XH/) and added the changes **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/adamhuffman/q7Mhf/)**.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot! I try this with YerSlider inside my modal. it works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Foundation 6 (my legacy project was on 6.2.4), i fixed this by adding the following css code:

```
div.gallery-in-modal .orbit-container {
    height: auto !important;
}
div.gallery-in-modal .orbit-container .orbit-slide {
    max-height: initial !important;
}
```